# c# int[] array to byte[] array only LSB

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, type-conversion

What is fastest way to write int[] array to byte[] array, but only LSB (last 8 bits)? I used `for` loop and bitmask `bArray[i] = (byte)(iArray[i] & 0xFF)`, but array is very long (+900k) and this take about 50ms. Do you know maybe other faster option?

Comment: Are you saying you want the LSB of each int in the int array into the byte array?

Comment: You need to process almost a million items faster than 50ms... have you thought about parallelizing to a GPU? Other than that I think you are probably running into CPU limits here

Comment: @bpgeck yes, LSB of each int in int array to byte array. I.e. 200 LSB values of 16 bit int array to 200 values of 8 bit byte array.

Comment: @drew_w I know that this is very large amount of data, but I want to know fastest option in C#.

Comment: Given the comments below, if you are processing image data the best option is going to be to use low level operating system instructions like BitBlt and MemCpy (http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/msvcrt.memcpy). These can be called via a PInvoke and should provide optimal performance. Hopefully that helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can try parallelizing the workload:

```
Parallel.For(0,iArray.Length, i => bArray[i] = (byte)(iArray[i] & 0xFF));
```

This will spawn multiple threads to do the conversion. It *tends* to be faster on my machine, but, will sometimes take longer due to the overhead of spawning multiple threads.

What are you doing that 50ms is too slow?

Comment: I want to display image array, but my function takes only bytes as parameters - 256 grayscale is enough and is faster than 16 bit.

Answer (score 1):

Part of the slowness comes from the need to read more data than you need: when you do

```
array[i] & 0xFF
```

you read the entire four bytes of an `int`, only to drop three most significant ones.

You could avoid this overhead with unsafe code. Keep in mind that the approach below assumes little endian architecture:

```
static unsafe void CopyLsbUnsafe(int[] from, byte[] to) {
    fixed (int* s = from) {
        fixed (byte* d = to) {
            byte* sb = (byte*) s;
            int* db = (int*)d;
            int* end = db + to.Length/4;
            while (db != end) {
                *db++ = (*(sb + 0) << 0)
                      | (*(sb + 4) << 8)
                      | (*(sb + 8) << 16)
                      | (*(sb + 12) << 24);
                sb += 16;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above code re-interprets the `int` array as an array of bytes, and the array of bytes as an array of integers. Then it reads every 4-th byte into the destination array using a pointer, writing to the destination in groups of four bytes using an integer assignment.

My testing shows a respectable 60% improvement over a simple loop.